# How to update space in oracle update query

Tags: sql, oracle

below is my table data

```
Accno

1234 5678 9876
5678 1235 4569
8520 7410 9630
```

I want to update my table values without any space

```
Accno

123456789876
567812354569
852074109630
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `REPLACE` here:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET Accno = REPLACE(Accno, ' ', '');
```

If you might have other types of whitespace characters, you might want to use a regex replacement, along these lines:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET Accno = REGEXP_REPLACE(Accno, '[[:space:]]+)', '');
```